# Java 'java.util.InputMismatchException' error when compiling

Tags: java, debugging

I'm quite new to Java. I have this assignment where I should write a program that calculates a customer’s monthly bill. It should ask the user to enter the letter of the package the customer has purchased (A, B, or C) and the number of minutes that were used. It should then display the total charges.

The specifications are:

> An Internet service provider has three different subscription packages for its customers:
>
> Package A: For $39.99 per month 450 minutes of access are provided. Additional minutes  are $.45 per minute. Package B: For $59.99 per month 900 minutes of access are provided. Additional hours are $.40 per minute. Package C: For $69.99 per month unlimited access is provided.

Here's my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class assignment2
    {
    
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
    //declaration section 
    
    double AddTime;
    double Charges;
    double Saving;
    double Bill;
    int Subscription;
    int TimeMin;
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    //ask user subscription
    System.out.println("Please enter you subscription (A,B, or C) ");
    Subscription = input.nextInt ();
    
    //if user choses subscription A
     switch (Subscription)
    {
            case 'a':
                    case 'A':
    System.out.println("Enter amount of minutes spent this month ");
    TimeMin = input.nextInt ();
        if (TimeMin < 450)
        {
        AddTime = TimeMin - 450 ;
        Charges = AddTime * 0.45;
        System.out.println("The charges are: $" + Charges);
        Bill = 39.99 + Charges;
        System.out.println("Your bill this month will be: $" + Bill);
        System.out.println(" ");
    //mention the user the savings with other subscriptions
    Saving = Bill - 59.99;
    System.out.println("With package B you would have saved: $" + Saving);
    Saving = Bill - 69.99;
    System.out.println("With package C you would have saved: $" + Saving);
    
        }
        else
        {System.out.println("Your bill is $39.99 this month ");}
                              break;
                    case 'b':
                    case 'B':
    // ask user for the amount of minutes used
    System.out.println("Enter amount of minutes spent this month ");
    TimeMin = input.nextInt();
        if (TimeMin < 900)
        {
        AddTime = TimeMin - 900;
        Charges = AddTime * 0.40;
        System.out.println("The charges are: $" + Charges);
        Bill = 59.99 + Charges;
        System.out.println("Your bill this month will be: $" + Bill);
        System.out.println(" ");
    //mention the user the savings with other subscriptions
    Saving = Bill - 69.99;
    System.out.println("With package C you would have saved: $" + Saving);
    
        }
        else
        {System.out.println("Your bill is $59.99 this month ");}
                break; 
    
                    case 'c':
                    case 'C':   
    // ask user for the amount of minutes used
        System.out.println("Enter amount of minutes spent this month ");
        TimeMin = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your bill is $69.99 this month you have unlimited access to our service!");
    
    break;
    default:
    System.out.println("That is not A, B, or C!");  
    }
    
    System.out.println("Thanks for using our service!");
    }
           
    }
```

once I tried compiling it gave me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
        at assignment2.main(assignment2.java:21)
```

I haven't solved it. Any idea how should fix my code?

Comment: Javascript is not Java. Please try to make an effort to learn the name of the language you're trying to write code in, and tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: `System.out.println("Please enter you subscription (A,B, or C) ");` does this look like it will take integer input? If not why have `Subscription = input.nextInt ();`?

Comment: `Subscription = input.nextInt ();` means that the user should be keying in  digits. Use `Scanner.next()`.

Comment: A few side notes: This 'error' is no compiling error as the title states. It's a **Runtime Exception**. With compiler errors the program wouldn't even run/compile. The 2nd thing I like to mention is you should consider informing yourself about java coding conventions like the [Google java Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) to make your code more readeable and maintainable for others. A third note: When asking questions keep it professional and objective. Cut words like 'lol','nerds' and so on. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major reason for the Exception thrown is that you attempt to read an **integer value** from the **InputStream** (stdin / System.in in your case).
Hoever since you prompt the user to input either A,B or C it's quite likely that he will input one of these **characters**.

According to the documentation [`Scanner#nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) attempts to parse a given **String** to an integer. Which means a String like "526" would return an integer 526. What should A,B or C represent in this case? The answer is simple. Those aren't values between the range of 0-9 and therefore a `InputMismatchException` is thrown at runtime to indicate that the input could not be parsed.

There are many possibilities to solve such issues. To keep your current switch case structure you could go with something like this:

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.println( "Enter A,B or C" );

    // read from console
    String rawInput = sc.nextLine();
    // remove unneccessary whitespaces.
    String trimmedInput = rawInput.trim();
    // assure that our string was not only containing whitespaces.
    if ( trimmedInput.length() > 0 )
    {
      // assign the value
      char value = trimmedInput.charAt( 0 );
      switchInputValue( value );
    }
  }

  private static void switchInputValue( char value )
  {
    switch ( value )
    {

      case 'a':
      case 'A':
        doSomethingForA();
        break;

      case 'b':
      case 'B':
        doSomethingForB();
        break;
      default:
        // get creative here
        // example:
        System.out.println("Something went wrong. - Wong input value.");
        break;

    }
  }
}
```

---

Note: Since Java 7 we're able to directly switch over Strings however if you it wouldn't make a big difference in your case. For the sake of completation the following code snippet would do exactly the same as above but without gettinga  single *char value* :

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println( "Enter A,B or C" );
    String rawInput = sc.nextLine();
    String trimmedInput = rawInput.trim();
    if ( trimmedInput.length() > 0 )
    {
      // switching our String
      switchInputValue( trimmedInput );
    }
  }

  private static void switchInputValue( String value )
  {
    switch ( value )
    {

      case "a":
      case "A":
        doSomethingForA();
        break;

      case "b":
      case "B":
        doSomethingForB();
        break;
      default:
        doSomethingIfEverythingElseFails();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see there is not a big difference except for the type of the parameter od the method has been changed to `String value` amd the cases are marked with `" "` instead of `' '`. Still since you are excepting a single character as iput I would consider the first approach instead of the 2nd one.

Hope that helped with your issue.

Comment: Thanks it really helped me out, I know my stile still so c++ but ill get the hang of Java... Anyways once again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should change `input.nextInt();` to `input.nextLine();` and `int Subscription` to `String Subscription` and any `'` to `"` in `switch case`